# Cannot deploy EAR to JBoss from Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, deployment, jboss

Im trying to deploy a EAR file (not exploded) to JBoss 7.4.3 from IDEA 15, but I get this exception:

```
[2016-03-07 12:17:17,292] Artifact MY_APP:ear: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2016-03-07 12:17:17,304] Artifact MY_APP:ear: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MY_APP.ear\".\"logic.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MY_APP.ear\".\"logic.jar\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"logic.jar\" of deployment \"MY_APP.ear\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011058: Failed to install component SomeService
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014546: More than one EJB found with interface of type 'com.project.SomeMgrBeanLocal' for binding com.project.Some.SomeService/SomeMgr. Found: [View of type com.project.SomeMgrBeanLocal for org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessComponentDescription{serviceName=service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MY_APP.ear\".\"SomeMgr.jar\".component.SomeMgrBean}@5e125506, View of type com.project.SomeMgrBeanLocal for org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessComponentDescription{serviceName=service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MY_APP.ear\".\"webapp.war\".component.SomeMgrBean}@666c4657, View of type com.project.SomeMgrBeanLocal for org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateless.StatelessComponentDescription{serviceName=service
```

In the same time when I build EAR artifact from console and after that I try deploy the EAR from admin console of the same JBoss, I can do this and this works fine.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: There are poblems deploying `Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MY_APP.ear\".\"logic.jar\` your logic.jar. Is this an ejb modul? Can you post the jboss log?

Comment: Yes, logic.jar is an ejb modul. Sorry, but it isn't possible to post JBoss logs.

Comment: Please check if the logic.jar is at the right place in your intellij artifact. Is the logic.jar build from your source code or is it an external dependency?